# React format string date to date format timzone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime, timezone

When I call my function:

```
formatDate(new Date("2020-06-08T10:37:05.915+0000")

function formatDate(tstamp) {
  return new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-GB", {
    year: "numeric",month: "2-digit",day: "2-digit",
    hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit",second: "2-digit"
  }).format(tstamp);
}
```

My output is: 08/06/2020, 12:37:05
why I got (12:37:05) instead (10:37:05) my timezone is GMT+2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the input is GMT+0000 and you are GMT+0200 which is 2 hours ahead Greenwich Mean Time. The `format` method formats a date without changing its time value.